# Scraping text from string

Tags: php, string, web-scraping

Sorry if it's unclear (I am a beginner when it comes to php).

Say I've got a string that I scraped $results that I want to further scrape it's information and assign it to variables. The incoming information changes every time.

An example of **$results** would be if echoed:

```
Array ( [name] => Tennismix2 [count] => 1 [frequency] => On demand [version] => 9 [newdata] => 1 [lastrunstatus] => success [thisversionrun] => Wed Nov 12 2014 08:54:58 GMT+0000 (UTC) [lastsuccess] => Wed Nov 05 2014 08:28:44 GMT+0000 (UTC) [results] => Array ( [collection1] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [Bondsnummer] => 21169152 [Naam] => Baal, A.J.W. van [Geslacht] => M [Spelersterkte Enkel] => 4 [Spelersterkte Dubbel] => 4 ) ) ) )
```

I want to extract 5 things from this string: -the 8 digit number directly behind "Bondsnummer", the name (which obviously varies in length) directly behind "Naam", The sex directly behind "Geslacht", The number behind "Enkel", and the number behind "Dubbel"

I've tried doing this using substring like such:

```
$bondsnummer = substr($response, 326, 8);
```

But I get in trouble when the length of the name makes the initial string longer or shorter.

Is there a smarter/better way of scraping from a string like this ?

Comment: this is a `print_r()` dump, wwhy would you parse that? just directly point it to which index you want to get in the array

Comment: Point to index like `echo $results['name'];` It will display name.

Answer (score 0):

Try having a look at Regex (regular expressions) to see if this might solve your problem:

Here is an example tutorial:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php

Answer (score 0):

to grab the 8 digit number you can access directly through:

```
$response['results']['collection1'][0]['Bondsnummer']
```

for name :

```
$response['results']['collection1'][0]['naam']  // and so on...
```

Comment: echo $response['results']['collection1'][0]['Bondsnummer']; gives me this:Warning: Illegal string offset 'results' in C:\xampp\htdocs\test\kimonobondsnummer.php on line 9

Warning: Illegal string offset 'collection1' in C:\xampp\htdocs\test\kimonobondsnummer.php on line 9

Warning: Illegal string offset 'Bondsnummer' in C:\xampp\htdocs\test\kimonobondsnummer.php on line 9
{

Comment: try echo '<pre>';print_r($response);echo '</pre>'; and then paste the output. Then the offset will be clear to retrieve values